# How to determine if a .NET dll is legitimately from Microsoft?

Tags: .net

I suspect an asp.net mvc dll we're using has been modified because:

1. There is no matching symbolic information on the Microsoft Symbol Servers.
2. The dll in question is not strong named.

How can I confirm conclusively whether or not a dll is indeed from Microsoft and not changed?

PS - I realize this sounds like a security question, and it's definitely valid in that context, but my intent is to find out if my predecessors included all the code I need to maintain the project.

Comment: so you have a known DLL, that you believe may have been modified? have you considered pulling a new copy down from a trusted source (like microsoft.com) and confirming that its hash matches your dlls? http://sourceforge.net/projects/md5summer/

Comment: The strong name is a pretty good indicator. The "official" microsoft binaries have a public key token of 31bf3856ad364e35.

Comment: @vcsjones It depends on the assembly.  b03f5f7f11d50a3a seems to be more common.  Also, b77a5c561934e089 is quite frequent.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I was giving the strong name for System.Web.Mvc, which is what the question was pertaining to, but yes you are right.

Answer (score 4):

"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\sn.exe" -T

for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\sn.exe" -T c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\system.xml.dll
```

Compare the outputted public key token with the expected public key token.

For what it's worth, if you reference a strong named DLL, it will always only load the DLL with the same strong name (you can get around different versions, but that's a separate topic).  you can verify the correct (legitimate) DLL is being used by looking at the source of your csproj file to make sure the legitimate public key token is being used.

Comment: ... and then what? What output do you get from the tool if the DLL is legitimate (or if it isn't) :)

Comment: @jalf you have to compare against the expected token.

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more helpful if it included that information. :)

Answer (score 2):

If a assembly is digitally signed then you can be sure of its owner. They say that a picture is worth a thousand words, so here goes...

Select the assembly is question and view its properties as per the image below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could create a self-signed certificate with all the same information, how does this show that the DLL is the correct one?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing one last step: the Certification Path pane should show the entire chain of trust, so you can verify that the so-called Microsoft which signed the assembly is actually trusted by someone else to *be* Microsoft, etc.

Comment: Hello @PeterRitchie, I have uploaded the last one. Its just that the images were getting too large and complicated. I am new to SO and was just trying out images as i felt it was best suited for this example.

Comment: @jalf, Thanks for your input! I have added the last one I had missed out for the reasons stated above.

Comment: That just verifies the certificate in the dll is "OK" (i.e. the CA is known), it doesn't verify the source of the certificate.  e.g. if I had access to replace a .NET dll, then I'd have access to add my own trusted CA and reproduce all the screens you've show without ever using a true Microsoft certificate.  You need to validate the certificates public key (or the public key's token) is the same key you expect it to be.

Comment: Yeah, I looked for that before, but I don't even have the 'Digital Signatures' tab.  Upon inspection of the other dlls in my Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/ directory (the file I'm talking about is in my project dir), those files don't appear to have that tab either.  The specific file I'm looking at is Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll

Comment: Hello @JohnMacIntyre, I downloaded the [Mvc4Futures](http://nuget.org/packages/Mvc4Futures/) NuGet package, that contains Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll version 4.0.0.0 and I don't see any digital signatures tab implying that it is not digitally signed. Its probably not strong named as it included unsupported prototype features and may be strong named when it gets official, hopefully :)

Comment: @PatrickCanuteD'Souza -p Thank you. So if it's not signed, is there another way to figure out if it's been modified or not?

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre: Since its not signed and its only the assembly you are concerned with, you will have to trust the [MVC4Futures](http://nuget.org/packages/Mvc4Futures/) NuGet package or download the [aspnetwebstack](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) project of CodePlex and build it yourself.